# I need help showing something is a linear continuous operator.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Define $T:C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1])$ by $T(f)(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xtf(t)dt$ I want to show that $T$ is a continuous linear operator.Showing the linear part is easy enough, but I am not quite sure how to show the continuity part. I am trying to show that there exists $c$ s.t. $||T(f)||\le c||f||$.Or I might need to use that $\{||T(f)(x)||  : \ f(x)\le 1 \}\le \infty$ I am not quite sure... any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $f(0) \le \lVert f\rVert$ so we needn't worry about that piece. The harder part is the integral. The way to do this is to note that:

$$\left|\int_0^x tf(t)\,dt\right|\le\int_0^xt|f(t)|\,dt \le \int_0^x t\lVert f\rVert \,dt.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes ty, this is perfect.

Comment: dont I need $\max_{x\in [0,1]}\left|\int_0^x tf(t)\,dt\right|\le\int_0^xt|f(t)|\,dt \le \int_0^x t\lVert f\rVert \,dt.$ ?

Comment: @tmpys You need to show the max is at most $C\Vert f\Vert$ for some $C$. Take the upper limit of the integral in the rightmost expression to be $1$ and evaluate.